# Is there a way to automatically answer for user prompt when doing ssh in a shell script without using expect or spawn?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to test ssh trust between a linux box against 12 other linux boxes using a shell script and I'm trying to pass user input as 'yes' for the question below  automatically.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

but the script is failing with error 'Host key verification failed'. I manually executed the ssh command with << EOT on one of the server but the I still get user prompt question. Is there any-other way to pass input value for user prompts automatically while running ssh command?

Note: I cannot use spawn or except do you some system limitation and I cannot install them due to organisations access restrictions.

I tried with the following options but none of them worked for me

````
[command] << [EOT, EOL, EOF]
echo 'yes'
[EOT, EOL, EOF]

yes | ./script.sh

printf "yes" | ./script.sh

echo "yes" | ./script.sh

./script.sh 'read -p "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?";echo "yes"'

sh```
for server in `cat server_list` ; do
    UPPER_MACHINE_NAME=`echo $server | cut -d '.' -f 1`
    UPPER_MACHINE_NAME=${UPPER_MACHINE_NAME^^}
    ssh -tt user@$UPPER_MACHINE_NAME << EOT
    echo 'yes'
    touch /usr/Finastra/sshtest.txt
    EOT
done
```
````

Comment: The reason, why ssh is asking about your trust of the server fingerprint, is a security feature. There are two ways around this: (1) add the host finger-prints to the appropriate known_hosts file (usually ~/.ssh/known_hosts) via `ssh-keyscan -H $host >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` thereby expressing your trust in those host finger-prints, or (2) if you absolutely don't like security, you could disable host key verification in your ssh call with `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ...`, which is **NOT RECOMMENDED**.

Comment: By the way: ssh redirects its standard input (e.g. `<< `) to the standard input of the remote shell, which is why you cannot easily automate ssh interaction. This is also a security feature.